# Rails AJAX link_to not refreshed controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my Rails 5 app, Doctor/Admin have to create a `Caregiver` with linked `Patient` (new object `CaregiverPatient` represents that). During this process, inside the `registrants_controller#new`, Doctor/Admin search for a Patient (which is done by Ransack gem) and from the result he/she push `Add Patient` button to add `Patient` to initialized `CaregiverPatient` object from `caregiver_patient#new` and display `@patient.full_name` inside the form.

In order not to lose already filled form fields, everything must be done asynchronously. I've tried to do so with AJAX, below my code:

`registrant_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @registrant = Registrant.new
  @patient = Registrant.find(session[:patient_id_to_add_caregiver]) if session[:patient_id_to_add_caregiver]
end
```

`registrants/_new_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @registrant do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :registration do |registration| %>
    <% if @patient %>
      <div id="add-patient"></div>
    <% else %>
      <%= required_text_field_group registration, @registrant, :registrant_id, "Patient Added", {}, { disabled: true } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

# some other logic (...)

# patient search result
<% @registrants do |registrant| %>
  <%= link_to 'Add Patient', new_registrant_link_path(registrant), remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

`Add Patient` button triggers caregiver_patients#new action:

```
#caregiver_patient_controller.rb

class CaregiverPatientsController < ApplicationController
  # new_registrant_link_path
  def new
    session[:patient_id_to_add_caregiver] = params[:registrant_id].to_i

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
      format.js { render action: 'patient_to_caregiver', notice: 'Patient Added' }
    end
  end
end
```

AJAX request is made:

```
#views/caregiver_patients/patient_to_caregiver.js.erb

$("#add-patient").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'registrants/add_patient') %>");
```

`views/registrants/_add_patient.html.erb`

```
Patient Added: <%= @patient.full_name %>
```

But surprisingly gets an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: Patient Added: <%= @patient.full_name %>
```

Which probably means that `registrants_controller#new` was not refreshed under the hood somehow. What have I missed?

Comment: You have missed the fact that each request still happens in its own context even when you're making `.js.erb` soup. That request is processed by `CaregiverPatientsController#new` so it doesn't have access to an instance variable set in a completely different controller.

Comment: @max I understand that but the request comes from the `registrants_controller#new`. Shouldn't the `format.html` therefore redirect the user to this controller and `format.js` prevent reloading the page by rendering its own partial but under the hood request was still made? If so I should be able to get `@patient` from `registrants_controller#new`. If not Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Nah, you getting your head stuck in the whole conceptual problem that Server Side Concerns creates as it makes a mush of the client and server side concerns. You may have a persistent "session" on the client side where the DOM is updated with ajax requests instead of reloading the page but on the server side each request is actually just happening in isolation.

Comment: Just because you are sending an ajax request doesn't mean the code is somehow executed in the context of another controller. It still works exactly the same as with "normal" html requests. The server doesn't know what's actually going on in the client.

Comment: Exactly! so on the server side redirection from `CaregiverPatientsController#new` to `registrants_controller#new` should be made and because I'm sending `session[:patient_id_to_add_caregiver]` in such redirection I should have access to the @patient from `registrants_controller#new` because in fact `new_registrant_path` has been declared in `format.html { redirect_to request.referer }`. Do I understand this completely wrong?

Comment: No - your expectations are incorrect. There is no redirect happening. You're using `remote: true` which sends an XHR request for `application/javascript`. This will trigger the `format.js` response. Using `request.referrer` is also problematic on its own as browsers can opt out of sending it as it's a privacy concern.

Comment: @max Hm... so there's no chance of achieving what I want?

Comment: On the contrary - its pretty easy to just use ajax to get a list of search suggestions from a controller and use that to update the view. I would really just avoid the whole `.js.erb` mess and just write an autocomplete endpoint that returns a list of patients as JSON and then use that to create option tags (there are a ton of libraries for this).

Comment: I get search results from AJAX which is `<% @registrants do |registrant| %>` thing. I'm not quite follow what you mean by "autocomplete endpoint", could you please share some code or example/link so that I can understand it?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials for how to do an autocomplete/search. Its basically just an index action that takes a search parameter and returns a list of records that are matches as JSON. https://joelc.io/dynamic-autocomplete-rails-6

Comment: @max oh that's what you meant. That's not an option - the search engine is ready and dynamic search is not an option (it's more advance search, the design does not provide for it etc) besides search is not an issue. Now I'm thinking of using the search result to display the selected Patient (after pressing "Add Patient") inside the registration form `registrants/_new_form.html.erb` but don't know how to do so for now.